# Why noncopyable class works for container?

Tags: c++, boost

```
class A : boost::noncopyable
{
    B b;
public:
    A(){}
    A(const B& b) : b(b) {}
    A& operator=(const B& b) {return something;}
}
```

Why the following code works? How does the copy happen when we need to resize myMap?

```
boost::unordered_map<int, A> myMap;
```

Comment: It happens because `A(const B& b) : b(b) {}
    A& operator=(const B& b) {return something;}` undoes what `: boost::noncopyable` does.  Why are you providing copy operations if you don't want the class to be copyable?

Comment: "Why the following code works?" does it? I'd expect "something not defined" or something like that

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38959218/how-does-boostnoncopyable-work?rq=1

Comment: @NathanOliver But the parameter for `A(const B& b) : b(b) {} A& operator=(const B& b) {return something;}` is `B`, not `A`. Can you explain the details? Thanks!

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 I'd like to know the steps in detail when we resize `myMap`.

Comment: your example is a bit confusing. What is `B`? Please provide a [mcve]